# Implementing empty matrix?

Tags: matrix

Matlab is famous for having implementation of empty matrices. The Matlab tutorial says *"As
far as we know, the literature on the algebra of empty matrices is itself empty. We’re not
sure we’ve done it correctly, or even consistently, but we have found the idea useful."*

For instance, the determinant of the empty matrix $0\times0$ should be equal to $1$. I tested this in Mathematica... No, it does not work.

I wonder, how to implement an empty matrix in Mathematica, for experimentation. So that I could try to test various functions and operators on it (like trace, permanent, logarithm).

I want the implementation to test its properties, so an advice to hard-code the known properties into implementantion is useless.

Answer (score 2):

```
Unprotect[Det];
Det[{{}}] = 1;
Protect[Det];

Unprotect[Tr];
Tr[{{}}] = 0;
Protect[Tr];

Unprotect[Transpose];
Transpose[{{}}] = {{}};
Protect[Transpose];
```

Problem is: What is the *type* of an empty matrix? Exact, integer, machine double...?

In general, I do not recommend to mess with built-ins like this...

Comment: Can I take a logarithm now?

Comment: Not sure. Can you?

Comment: If empty matrix is properly implemented, then MatrixFunction should work on it as well.

Comment: @Anixx Some quirks: According to `Dimensions[{{}}]`, `{{}}` is a $1 \times 0$ matrix, and `SquareMatrixQ[{{}}]` seems to agree. `Compile[{}, Most[Most /@ {{0}}] // Dimensions][]` seems to construct a $0\times0$ matrix in the WVM, but you can't take the `Det` of it. There may well be a reason why *the literature on the algebra of empty matrices is itself empty*.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I won't continuous on this. ^^

Comment: @MichaelE2 an article on the topic: ftp://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/Approx/empty.pdf

Comment: @Anixx I grasp the concept, but how do you propose to represent an empty matrix? IMO, `{}` comes closest, but it does not distinguish a $0\times0$ matrix from a $0\times3$ matrix.